# create list of relevant resources by tagging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tagging, acts-as-taggable-on

I am using the gem acts-as-taggable-on to tag my resources. 
I wonder if there is an efficient way (e pre defined method, etc) to choose a list of say 5 resources with highest number of coincident tags.

Of curse I can write a double loop and then order the result, but may be there is a better way.

Thanks in advance

UPDATE

I wrote this code for finding three most similar tips for given "tip"

```
def similar_tips(tip)
  if tip.is_a?(Tip)
    sim_tips=Tip.all.map{ |t| [t,(t.tag_list & tip.tag_list).size]}.sort_by {|a,n| n}.reverse[0..2]
    sim_tips.map{|t,n| t}
  end
end
```

It actually works, but looks ugly for me =)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you post the code you've tried?

Comment: @Ben I added the code